# How can I handle a JSON File in a multi label classification problem?

Tags: python, keras, neural-network, deep-learning, multilabel-classification

I have a multi-label problem. I have read many tutorials and all work with CSV. But I have a JSON. An image can have one to three labels. This is what the JSON looks like: `{"PIC_NAME": ["Label1"], "PIC_NAME": ["Label2", "Label6"], "PIC_NAME": ["Label20"], "PIC_NAME": ["Label4"], "PIC_NAME": ["Label5"], "PIC_NAME": ["Label1"], "PIC_NAME": ["Label15"], ...`

The CSV work with binary labels. But I only have Strings. There are 20 different labels. If it should be like in the tutorials, then a picture should be marked with 23 binary numbers. If the label (for example Label1) is true, there is a 1 and all other labels are set to 0. I work with Keras.

Does anyone have any idea how I can solve the problem with a JSON? This is an example of a tutorial I have read: https://www.analyticsvidhya.com/blog/2019/04/build-first-multi-label-image-classification-model-python/

As an example we have a picture with a cat, a dog and a bird. The picture shows a dog and a bird. Then it should look like this: 0 1 1. Because there is no cat in the picture, the first value is 0. I wish it could look like in the tutorial above

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If i understood your problem, you want to replace ["Label1"] by [1 0 0 ... ], i.e. one hot encoding your labels?

If yes, you can for example look at [this](https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2018/05/07/multi-label-classification-with-keras/) where there is a multi-labels problem.

So you can for example do something like that:

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import MultiLabelBinarizer

labels = [("blue", "jeans"),("blue", "dress"),("red", "dress"),("red", "shirt"), 
         ("blue", "shirt"),("black", "jeans")]

mlb = MultiLabelBinarizer()
labels = mlb.fit_transform(labels)

print(labels)
```

It prints:

[image]

Then you have your labels one-hot encoded.

In your problem you'll have ["Label2", "Label6"] instead of clothing.

EDIT: if you have only one label instead of two, it's also working:

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import MultiLabelBinarizer

labels = [("blue",),("blue", "dress"),("red", "dress"),("red", "shirt"), 
         ("blue", "shirt"),("black", "jeans")]

mlb = MultiLabelBinarizer()
labels = mlb.fit_transform(labels)

print(labels)
```

[image]

To have an index of your classes, you can use:

```
print(mlb.classes_)
```

EDIT2:

For your example:

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import MultiLabelBinarizer

labels = [("Label1",),("Label2",),("Label3",),("Label4","Label1"),        
         ("Label4","Label5")]

mlb = MultiLabelBinarizer()
labels = mlb.fit_transform(labels)

print(labels)

print(mlb.classes_)
```

[image]

EDIT3:

These will work:

```
labels = [["Label1"],["Label2"],["Label3"],["Label4","Label1"], 
         ["Label4","Label5"]]

labels = [("Label1",),("Label2",),("Label3",),("Label4","Label1"), 
         ("Label4","Label5")]
```

This won't (without commas):

```
labels = [("Label1"),("Label2"),("Label3"),("Label4","Label1"), 
         ("Label4","Label5")]
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Do I need to know all the label combinations that exist? I have 23 different labels and all can be combined with each other. Does the order matter? Does it have to be "("blue", "shirt")" or can it also be ("shirt", "blue")?

Comment: The order doesn't matter. Using sklearn's method, you just need to feed the "MultiLabelBinarizer" with all your labels and it will understand all the different labels that exist in your dataset. You don't need to know all the label combinations that exist.

Comment: So can it look like this? labels = [("Label1",),("Label2"),("Label3"),("Label4"), etc.]

Comment: print(mlb.classes_) gives me this Output ['A' 'B' 'C' 'F' 'G' 'H' 'M' 'N' 'P' 'R' 'S' 'T' 'U' 'W' 'Z' 'a' 'b' 'c'
 'd' 'e' 'g' 'h' 'i' 'k' 'l' 'm' 'n' 'o' 'p' 'r' 's' 't' 'u' 'v' 'w' 'y'] , not the Labels

Comment: If you give the MultiLabelBinarizer something like:
labels = [["Label1"],["Label2"],["Label3"],["Label4","Label1"],["Label4","Label5"]]

it will work fine. If you replace the '[' by parenthesis inside the list, you need to don't forget the commas!

Comment: Yes I needed [] instead of (). Thank you!